# Access files on Ubuntu PC from Windows PC

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

I came across a few articles but wasn't able to achieve it probably because of I don't know much about Ubuntu.

I have 2 laptops. The first with Ubuntu and the other with Windows, connected to the same network.

A) I want to access Ubuntu files through the [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) IDE on my Windows machine.

B) Also, I want to pass the commands to the Ubuntu terminal through windows cmd/powershell.

How can I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Mobaxterm](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/download-home-edition.html) for this by using the target ip.

You can connect to your ubuntu machine from windows using ssh port. This Connects to ubuntu machine terminal directly and there you have access to all the files on ubuntu machine where with one click you can transfer files from Ubuntu to Windows and from Windows to Ubuntu.

There is no need for any extra applications on ubuntu machine. Just ssh port should be opened and work

[image: Setup screen]

In setup screen just enter your hostname or ip address with port 22 leaving username untouched if required. Then save and connect. It connects to your ubuntu machine using ssh port. It might ask for credentials for the first time. You can save them if you want, so for the next time just click the saved ip address and it will open ubuntu's terminal directly

You can access all the files on ubuntu machine using the side menu on side toolbar as shown on the below image

[image: Files]

Answer (score 0):

For the whole purpose of accessing your machine remotely on a network, I suggest you `ssh` into it.

- First, you'd need a platform to do so, I strongly recommend `PuTTY` on your 
  Windows machine.
- Then, open a terminal on your Ubuntu machine and install an SSH server. Do this `sudo apt install openssh-server`.
- You'd then need to configure it properly, to do so, open and edit the config file using `sudo nano /etc/ssh/ssh_config`. SSH runs on a specific port, so find and uncomment the line containing something like `Port 22`. I suggest you do not change this number now. Also, comments are lines which begin with `#`.
- You can also change other settings like maximum tries one is allowed to log in, but they might not be necessary.
- Now, check the status of your server: `sudo service ssh status`.
- Regardless of the output, you can start or stop the server with `sudo service ssh start/stop`. So, start it up if it's not running already.
- Now, on your Windows machine, open PuTTY and enter the IP address of your Ubuntu machine and select SSH as connection type. The port number earlier comes into play here.
- Once done, just hit `Open` and a terminal will open up and ask you for your credentials.
- If you've done everything right, you'll now have all the access you'd want.